# The file '************.avro' may not render correctly as it contains an unrecognized extension. Event Hub - Capture Container in Storage Account

Tags: azure-eventhub

The file '************.avro' may not render correctly as it contains an unrecognized extension. Event Hub - Capture Container in Storage Account

I have an event hub which captures data in a container in a storage account.
I am sending messages from a java application.
When I open the message in the Event hub capture container(in storage account) and go to the .avro file blade, under the 'Edit' tab I see the file received along with the below message:-

The file '************.avro' may not render correctly as it contains an unrecognized extension. Event Hub - Capture Container in Storage Account

The actual contents of the message are showing in an encrypted format and I am not able to see the contents of the message.
Please help as to how I should be able to see the contents of the message.

Comment: That is a message provided purely by whatever client you are using to view it. It doens't mean there is anything wrong with the file, it just means whatever viewer you are using (azure portal) doesn't have the capability to render it. Open it in something that can render avro files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Storage Data Explorer can parse avro files w/o a proper schema provided for body. Try opening the file with a tool such as AvroEditor. You can find the editor here - http://avroeditor.sourceforge.net/

Comment: But I need to know that the message that I am getting:-
"The file '************.avro' may not render correctly as it contains an unrecognized extension." is this due to some configuration issue?What could I do to read it correctly from the portal without using any external tools

Comment: Avro is a binary file. Storage Data Explorer doesn't know how to handle it and that is why it is failing. Why do you want Storage to parse it?

Comment: _What could I do to read it correctly from the portal without using any external tools_ You can't. The portal won't render it. You need a third party tool. There is nothing wrong with your file

Answer (score 0):

Data Explorer ( preview) in ADLS gen-2 won't be able to show content for Parquet or Avro format files. If you wish to read file content create external table in data explorer. something like below :

```
.create external table ExTableavro (AppId:string,UserId:string,Email:string,TargetTitle:string,Params:string,EventEnqueuedUtcTime:datetime) 
kind=blob
partition by 
   AppId,
   bin(EventProcessedUtcTime, 1d)
dataformat=avro
( 
   h@'https://streamoutalds2.blob.core.windows.net/stream-api-raw-avro/logs/;secret Key'
)
with 
(
   folder = "ExternalTables"   
)
```

Note the Dataformat set as 'Avro'

Hope it Helps!